# Bash loop, print current iteration?

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

Say you have a simple loop

```
while read line
do
  printf "${line#*//}\n"
done < text.txt
```

Is there an elegant way of printing the current iteration with the output? Something like

```
0 The
1 quick
2 brown
3 fox
```

I am hoping to avoid setting a variable and incrementing it on each loop.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To do this, you would need to increment a counter on each iteration (like you are trying to avoid).

```
count=0
while read -r line; do
   printf '%d %s\n' "$count" "${line*//}"
   (( count++ ))
done < test.txt
```

EDIT: After some more thought, you can do it without a counter if you have bash version 4 or higher:

```
mapfile -t arr < test.txt
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
   printf '%d %s' "$i" "${arr[i]}"
done
```

The mapfile builtin reads the entire contents of the file into the array. You can then iterate over the indices of the array, which will be the line numbers and access that element.

Comment: Nice solution, though `mapfile` can be awfully memory hungry if you're dealing with large files.  Without knowing the OP's file size, I'd recommend going with something that runs through a pipe, and so is filesize agnostic.

Answer (score 31):

You don't often see it, but you can have multiple commands in the condition clause of a `while` loop. The following still requires an explicit counter variable, but the arrangement may be more suitable or appealing for some uses.

```
while ((i++)); read -r line
do
    echo "$i $line"
done < inputfile
```

The `while` condition is satisfied by whatever the last command returns (`read` in this case).

Some people prefer to include the `do` on the same line. This is what that would look like:

```
while ((i++)); read -r line; do
    echo "$i $line"
done < inputfile
```

Comment: @jordanm: `for` does something similar: `for ((i=0, j=14; i<=20; i++, j+=11))`. Also, you can read two (or more) lines from a file at a time: `while read -r oddline; read -r evenline; do echo "odd:  [$oddline] even: [$evenline]"; done < filename`

Answer (score 8):

You can use a range to go through, it can be an array, a string, a input line or a list.

In this example, i use a list of numbers [0..10] is used with an increment of 2, as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..10..2}; do 
   echo " $i times"
done
```

The output is:

```
 0 times
 2 times
 4 times
 6 times
 8 times
 10 times
```

To print the index regardless of the loop range, you have to use a variable "COUNTER=0" and increase it in each iteration "COUNTER+1".

my solution prints each iteration, the FOR traverses an inputline and increments by one each iteration, also shows each of words in the inputline:

```
#!/bin/bash 

COUNTER=0
line="this is a sample input line"

for word in $line; do        
    echo "This i a word number $COUNTER: $word"
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
done
```

The output is:

```
This i a word number 0: this
This i a word number 1: is
This i a word number 2: a
This i a word number 3: sample
This i a word number 4: input
This i a word number 5: line
```

to see more about loops: [enter link description here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)

to test your scripts: [enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

```
n=0
cat test.txt | while read line; do
  printf "%7s %s\n" "$n" "${line#*//}"
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

This will work in Bourne shell as well, of course.

If you really want to avoid incrementing a variable, you can pipe the output through grep or awk:

```
cat test.txt | while read line; do
  printf " %s\n" "${line#*//}"
done | grep -n .
```

or

```
awk '{sub(/.*\/\//, ""); print NR,$0}' test.txt
```

Comment: Edited to include an option for your final criteria.

Comment: I prefer the awk solution, though `sub(/.*\/\//, "");` is *not* the same as `${line#*//}`

Comment: Well ... the first part of your answer is pretty much identical to jordanm's, and the two additional ones seem to work just fine.  Chalk it up to the randomness of StackOverflow.  :-)

Comment: The `cat` is useless and `read` without `-r` will mangle backslashes in the input. This is a really inefficient way to reimplement `nl`.

Answer (score 1):

*Update:*  Other answers posted here are better, especially those of @Graham and @DennisWilliamson.

Something very like this should suit:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' <test.txt | nl -ba
```

You can add a `-v0` flag to the `nl` command if you want indexing from 0.

Comment: I don't have an `n1` command in FreeBSD, OSX or Illumos.  Where is it from?

Comment: Ah - pesky monospace fonts.  @thb, I think you'd still need something to strip lines up to the `//`, as `${line#*//}` does.  But you could certainly pipe the while loop through `nl`, just as I did with `grep -n .` in my answer.